# data reserved in functions in C

Tags: c, function, memory-address

In C programming language, a variable can have a memory address and a value.
And as I understood every function as well have an address and also data which allocated at that address. My question is what is the meaning of the data which these functions point to?

Comment: This question might be about the internal representation of functions and function-pointers. Well, the details are all platform-dependent (especially considering shared libraries / DLLs).

Answer (score 2):

The C programming language is (like every programming language) a *specification* (in some *report*). It is not a software. You probably should read the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (draft specification of [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)) report.

*Conceptually*, a function does not have any data in C (but its *code* may refer to static addresses, contain literal constants - including pointers- etc...). It has some behavior, practically implemented by some *code*. What is code is not defined by the C standard.

Practically speaking, and this depends upon the particular implementation (look into the difference between [Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) machine & [computer architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) and [Von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) ones), a function pointer is some address of [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) (often, the target of the `CALL` [machine instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) translating the C calls to it).

On desktops & laptops & tablets with some usual operating system (like Linux, Windows, MacOSX, iOS, Android...)  -all are Von Neumann architectures: x86-64 or ARM-, your process has a single [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) containing [code segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) and [data segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) and heap data. Then function pointers and data pointers are of the same kind, and it is *practically* meaningful to cast between them. A canonical example is the usage of POSIX [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html): you often cast its result to some function pointer (e.g. inside some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) which is [dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) with [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)). The address of a function is *practically speaking* the address of its first machine code instruction (sitting in some code segment in the *common* address space). Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) & [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303123/40065) for creative examples. Another useful example is [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/): they enable you to generate machine code at runtime, and to get a (fresh) function pointer from these.
Neither `dlsym` nor JIT libraries are *stricto sensu* conforming to the C standard, because in a purely standard conforming C program the set of functions is statically known and any function pointer should point to some *existing* function of the same signature (read about [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) & [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s), otherwise it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

On some [embedded computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) with a Harvard architecture (e.g. some [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/)), code and data sit in different spaces, and a code address might not have the same number of bits than a data address. On such systems, a cast between function and data pointers is meaningless (unless you dive into deep implementation details). The C standard was specified to be general enough to take such weird computers into account.

Read also a lot more about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) and [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). The C standard don't have them (hence [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) *conventionally* take some client data argument). You probably will learn a lot by reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). Read also about [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

Read also about [Operating Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system): If you use Linux (which I recommend, because it is mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code *you can study*), read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Read also [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

In other words: your question (on function pointers and addresses) has different approaches. A dogmatic programming language lawyer approach (and the issue is to understand deeply the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) of function pointers in the C standards; look also into [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) & [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)); a pragmatic operating system and implementation specific approach (and then it depends upon your computer, its [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), and its OS and even your particular C [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) -and version- and [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags; and you may even have some "magic mechanisms" -like `dlsym` & `dlopen` or JIT compilation libraries- to *create* functions at runtime; which is *magic* because the C standards don't think of that).

Answer (score 2):

You already got (good) answers, but I think some (obscure?) fact about C should be pointed out, regarding your question:

> In C programming language, a variable can have a memory address and a value.

Actually the defining property of a variable is that is *always* has a value – if it's uninitialized, semantically it still has a value, only that this value is the "undefined value" and reading the "undefined value" invokes undefined behaviour.

But, and this is important, not every variable in C does have an address! There is this little storage classifier `register`, which exact meaning most people do not fully comprehend. The most widespread – and wrong – interpretation is, that `register` means that the variable is to be placed in registers only. The problem is: There are instruction architectures in which registers do not exist, but C has been designed to be still viable for them.

The true meaning of the `register` classifier is, that you can not take the address of a variable that is *register*, which means you can not create pointers toward it.

The upshot of this is, that a variable that is `register` the only important thing is its value. And it is perfectly legal for the C compiler to generate code that completely discards the "place" (be it register, memory location or something entirely different) where its value came to be, as long as it able to faithfully recreate the value in a way, that it is semantically conforming to the program text. *This also implies that it is perfectly legal to perform a whole re-computation of whatever had to be executed to obtain the final value.* Which is why applying the `register` storage qualifier to variable may result in sudden increase of code size and *drop* of performance.

As such the `register` storage qualifier is not a mechanism for *optimizing* code, but should be treated as a special purpose tool for writing code that's neither time nor size critical but has to operate under very specific, tight constraints. One example would be for example bootloaders or system initialization code, which task it is to initialize memory access in the first place and have to operate with just a few bytes – or even none – of usable memory storage, but can re-compute values required for each step.

Comment: The question was more about function pointers than about variables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, but the question title itself is not clear about this. People who are wondering about "where variables in function scope" (aka automatic storage) reside may trip over this question. And I felt that particular sub-topic required to be addressed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation-and-C.html).
The C language supports two kinds of memory allocation through the variables in C programs:

- **Static allocation**: is what happens when you declare a static or global variable. Each static or global variable defines one block of space, of a fixed size. The space is allocated once, when your program is started (part of the exec operation), and is never freed.
- **Automatic allocation**: happens when you declare an automatic variable, such as a **function argument** or a **local variable**. The space for an automatic variable is allocated when the compound statement containing the declaration is entered, and is freed when that compound statement is exited.

In GNU C, the size of the automatic storage can be an expression that varies. In other C implementations, it must be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers point to blocks of machine instructions that get executed when you call the function.

Say you have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int plus_42(int x)
{
    int res=x+42;
    printf("%d + 42 = %d\n", x,res);
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    return plus_42(1);
}
```

If you compile it, link it, and run objdump -d on the result:

```
gcc plus_42.c && objdump -d a.out
```

you'll get (depending on your architecture, something like):

```
0000000000400536 <plus_42>:
  400536:       55                      push   %rbp
  400537:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40053a:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  40053e:       89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  400541:       8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  400544:       83 c0 2a                add    $0x2a,%eax
  400547:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  40054a:       8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  40054d:       8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  400550:       89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  400552:       bf 04 06 40 00          mov    $0x400604,%edi
  400557:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40055c:       e8 af fe ff ff          callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  400561:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400564:       c9                      leaveq 
  400565:       c3                      retq   

0000000000400566 <main>:
  400566:       55                      push   %rbp
  400567:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40056a:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40056f:       e8 c2 ff ff ff          callq  400536 <plus_42>
  400574:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400575:       c3                      retq   
  400576:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40057d:       00 00 00
```

plus some boilerplate.

Here, `0000000000400536` and `0000000000400566` are the addresses of `main` and `plus_42` (= the pointers that `main` and `plus_42` point to) respectively, and the hex numbers you see in the 2nd column is the data, which is decoded in the 3d column into human readable names of the machine instructions that the data represents.

Comment: I would suggest instead to compile with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O plus_42.c` and to examine the emitted `plus_42.s`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the suggestion. I feel actual assembly with the hexes and actual (nonsymbolic) addresses illustrates my point better.